# How to create generic producer for qualified and scoped CDI beans?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I am trying to do something like the following:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ PARAMETER, FIELD, METHOD, TYPE })
public @interface ForQueueName{
    String value();
}

public class JmsSenderProducer {
    @Produces
    @Any
    @ApplicationScoped
    public JmsSender createJmsSender(InjectionPoint ip) {
        ForQueueName annotation = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(ForQueueName.class);
        return new JmsSender(annotation.value());
    }
}

// Somewhere else
@Inject
@ForQueueName("java:/jms/queue/my.queue.name")
JmsSender myQueueSender;
```

Of course this does not work because

1. `@Any` does not work as a replacement for any qualified `@ForQueueName`
2. `InjectionPoint` cannot be used when producing `@ApplicationScoped` bean.

I know I could create `@Dependent` scoped beans with a nonbinding qualifier this way. But in my case I actually need a non dependent scoped bean.

Is something like the intended possible? If not, is there a particular reason why?

Cheers, Tilmann

EDIT: Fixed scope name from `@Default` to `@Dependent`

Comment: For something like that to be possible the spec would have to provide another object instead of `InjetctionPoint` that only provides access to the specified qualifiers of the injection.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should consider using `JMSContext` in your app.  Its a JMS 2.0 feature with a much cleaner API.

Second, your producer method should be annotated with `ForQueueName`.  For that to work, the `value()` attribute of `ForQueueName` needs to be marked as `@Nonbinding`.  This tells the CDI container that the value should not be considered when looking up the producer.

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ PARAMETER, FIELD, METHOD, TYPE })
public @interface ForQueueName{
    @Nonbinding String value();
}

public class JmsSenderProducer {
    @Produces
    @ForQueueName("")
    @Dependent // must be dependent to interrogate the injection point
    public JmsSender createJmsSender(InjectionPoint ip) {
        ForQueueName annotation = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(ForQueueName.class);
        return new JmsSender(annotation.value());
    }
}

// Somewhere else
@Inject
@ForQueueName("java:/jms/queue/my.queue.name")
JmsSender myQueueSender;
```

Comment: Actually I did do that at first. (See second last sentence in my question.) But this approach does not allow me to make the beans `@ApplicationScoped`. JMS was only an example, I also have other cases. But thanks anyway for those who come across and are looking to create `@Default` scoped beans :)

Comment: A guess I will not come around to write a seperate application scoped bean class or producer method for each queue I like to address. I hoped to avoid that since it somehow contradictes the open closed priciple. Maybe there is another but less beautiful way to do that using the bean manager or as a protable extension. But then again the effort will not pay off.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up scope name and used `@Default` instead of `@Dependent`. I edited the post.